# toLocaleString to show locale currency doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a problem with `toLocaleString()` to render on IE10, I believe this isn't supported in IE10. wondering if there's another work-around to show locale currency? Though I could replace `toLocalString` to currency `string` instead `$/£` but I don't think that's a good way of handling currency.

```
var priceLocale = parseFloat(value.price);
switch (getCountryCode) {
case 'US':
     priceLocale = priceLocale.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })
     break;
default:
     priceLocale = priceLocale.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, the toLocaleString() function seems to work in IE 11 but not in IE 10 as I tried in with this [js fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lv9u2gq/1/) and IE emulating modes.

To quickly respond to your problem, you can process this way without using toLocaleString():

```
var price = "50.3";
var priceLocale = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);
getCountryCode = "US"
switch (getCountryCode) {
  case 'US':
     priceLocale += '$';
     break;
   default:
     priceLocale += '£'
     break;
}
alert(priceLocale);
```

If you need to go farther and treat a lot of symbols, you'd rather take a look at some currency rest api in order to retrieve right symbol for a given country code.

Regards